# linux wait command only proceed if previous job successful putty

Tags: linux, wait

Im an end user that has access to Putty in order to run selective scripts on our server as they would run during our overnight batch process.

Some of these I run in sequence using

```
run_process.ksh kj_job1 & wait; run_process.ksh kj_job2
```

However kj_job1 can fail and kj_job2 would still run. Id like a way for kj_job2 to only proceed if kj_job1 was completed succesfully but i cant find a guide online to walk me through what i need to do.

My knowledge in this area is limited, i simply navigate to the directory where we have the file run_process.ksh and then add the job name i want to run. I recently found out about the & wait command in order to run strings and the () s i can run things in parallel.

Any help is apprecaited.

Comment: Why are you backgrounding and using `wait` here? Just run `run_process.ksh kj_job1 && run_process.ksh kj_job2`. This means "run the first command and if it is successful run the second command"

Comment: @larsks - If im honest, I have no idea. From what I found in the past the '& wait' command was meaning run this job and wait for it to finish before running the next job. No idea on the background aspect of it. Using the '&&' sounds exactly what I should be doing.

Is it possible to use that with simultaneous job runs as well, so I could do

'run_process.ksh kj_job1 && (run_process.ksh kj_job2 & run_process.ksh kj_job3) && run_process.ksh kj_job4'

Expectation being that would run kj_job1 and only if it succeeds would it run kj_job2 and kj_job3, then if both OK run kj_job4 ?